# how to get general percentage based on values and creating groups

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the mean number of days for values that are not equal to 0 and create groups."

Follow an example bellow:

```
ID Days Values
A  1    0
A  20   0
A  35   0
A  40   20
B  20   30 
B  50   23
B  110  30  
C  2    0   
C  60   0
C  90   30
C  120  90
```

"First values between 1-30 (B:20) (excluding 0), 31-60 (A: 40), and >=90 (C: 90) that are non-zero."

Output

```
group MeanDays
30  20
60  40
90  90
```

Comment: What if a value is between 61 and 89? Also, you dont have any `Values` that fall between 31-60, do you mean "first value of `Days` between..."?

Comment: Also, how are you arriving at "B: 46"? There is no value of 46 for ID "B", nor any that sum to it. Could you please edit your question to use a few more words and describe in more detail?

Comment: What matters are the first values that appear after zero; this is the reference of when production started.

Comment: I would like to know on which day production starts, that is, when there are values different from 0 in the 'values' column. If the interval starts between 0-30, I consider it in that group. The ultimate goal is to obtain an overall average of the sum of A, B, and C."

Comment: You have the row `B  20   30`, so how is the `MeanDays = 0` for `group = 30`? Why is the `B 20 30` row ignored?